# How to make a bool return true/false using the return function inside def in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, boolean

I was given a task to make a code which takes a word, checks if there are any vowels in it, then returns true if there are vowels inside the word, and false if no vowels are there inside the given word. This is what I wrote-

```
def search4vowels(word):
    vowels = set('aeiou')
    found = vowels.intersection(set(word))
    return(bool(found))
        
search4vowels('test')
```

Here, I was expecting `found` to contain either none (Or 0 vowels) or the value of the vowels. Then use the return function with bool
to get true or false depending on the value of the variable `found` However, when I ran the code, nothing was printed. I also changed the last line under def `return(bool(found))` to `return bool(found)` but that did not print anything either. This might be a really dumb/stupid question but I am really a beginner and actually don't know why nothing is getting printed despite the use of the return function. I checked on various websites also but did not understand why this was happening. Thanking you in advance, Have a great day ahead!

Answer (score 3):

Try adding a print statement to show the output:

```py
print('Result:', search4vowels('test'))
```